# How do repartition onto new column in aws glue?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Let say that datasource (csv) contains 2 columns: `code:string` and `my_date:date`. I try to add additional colum - `my_date_string:string` and write this into orc format with partition on that column:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "my_database", table_name = "my_table", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings =[
                   ("code", "string", "code", "string"),
                   ("my_date", "date", "my_date", "date"),
                   ("my_date_string", "string", "my_date_string", "string")
                   ],
    transformation_ctx="applymapping1")
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")

partitioned_dataframe = dropnullfields3.toDF().repartition("my_date_string")

partitioned_dataframe.toDF().write.orc(
    "s3://path/my_table",
    mode="append",
    partitionBy=['my_date_string'])

job.commit()
```

And I got exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u"requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.\nOld column names (2): code" \
                          u", my_date"
New column names (0): "
End of LogType:stdout
```

It looks like new column is not added at all!!! :(

But when I remove repartition statement it write all colums (e.g. all old and new one). How to fix this? How performa column "adding" before repartition srats?

Comment: Was this ever solved? running into the same thing!